# Could i use special characters to split aggregation? Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, string-aggregation

Can i ,without worrying, use special characters to split up the words?

For example:

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(users.name, '')
```

Comment: Could i have any problems with encoding?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name,  nothing. Its works.
But i wanna know in advance to prevent any issue)
And i`ve never do so.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine as long as you are using characters supported by your database encoding (check the parameter `server_encoding`).

I hope and expect that you are using the only sensible encoding here: `UTF8`. If yes, then you don't have to worry.